# Task chaining with shift using Celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Consider the following two-step algorithm:

```
Iteration 1: A1 A2 A3
Iteration 2:    B2 B3
```

Where task `B{i}` depends on tasks `A{i-1}` and `A{i}`.

*The question is how to execute this workflow with Celery such that*:

- *No `A` task is executed twice.*
- *Each `B` task can start as soon as both `A` tasks it depends on are finished?*

I've tried the following options but none has both properties.

**Option 1: Two groups**

I have split the two iterations into two separate groups like this.

```
result = group([A.s(1), A.s(2), A.s(3)]) | group([B.s(2), B.s(3)])
```

The problem with this execution is that the whole group with `A` tasks needs to finish before the `B` group can start. This leads to the desired result but not to the optimal utilization of the resources.

**Option 2: Chords**

```
result = group([
    chord([A.s(1), A.s(2)], B.s(2)),
    chord([A.s(2), A.s(3)], B.s(3))
])
```

The problem here is that `A.s(2)` is called twice. I can manage this inside of my application but that requires sort of distributed locks and more careful handling of what is already done and what needs to be done. Executing `A.s(2)` twice is not an option. Tasks are idempotent but the execution takes too long.

Comment: I believe you can accomplish what you need with clever use of [task links](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks).

Comment: @DejanLekic Can you elaborate on that a little bit more?

Comment: Dask is a fair better tool than Celery for this kind of thing. Are you tied to Celery?

Comment: @DHudson Not at all. I'll have a look into that. I'd still like to see an answer as there is a cost associated with switching over to another solution.

Comment: @tomas789 try this Dask solution https://gist.github.com/DomHudson/7a4d2b2f11186c880be1901b3954cf39. I am not aware of the best way to do this in Celery, so I didn't post an answer to this question.

Comment: @DHudson The example looks promising. I'll also try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar with chord itself:

```
@shared_task(name='notify_complete')
def notify_complete(*args, extra_id):
    # get list of result from a1,a2,a3 from args
    # execute b1, b2
    # extra_id: just in case you want to pass any var. you can ignore it.
    pass


chord([A.s(1), A.s(2), A.s(3)], notify_complete.s(extra_id=extra_id))
```

Comment: The function `notify_complete` is called only after all `A{i}` tasks are done right? That would make it equivalent to the _Option 1_ I mentioned in the question. My intent is different.